# Some Microsoft Edge files are corrupted - where do we find known good versions?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, microsoft-surface-pro-3, sfc

We used the System File Check tool to determine that the following are corrupt. [This KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833) suggests replacing the files with "known good versions." Where do we find known good versions of the following?

```
00001c55 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:106{53}]"MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.scale-125_contrast-white.png" of Microsoft-Windows-MicrosoftEdge, Version = 10.0.10240.16431, pA = amd64, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch

00001ca3 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:106{53}]"MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.scale-125_contrast-white.png" of Microsoft-Windows-MicrosoftEdge, Version = 10.0.10240.16431, pA = amd64, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch

00001ca4 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:156{78}]"Package_536_for_KB3081444~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.0.3081444-875_neutral"

00001ca7 [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:142{71},l:140{70}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\Assets"\[l:106{53}]"MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.scale-125_contrast-white.png"; source file in store is also corrupted

000053b5 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:106{53}]"MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.scale-125_contrast-white.png" of Microsoft-Windows-MicrosoftEdge, Version = 10.0.10240.16431, pA = amd64, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch

000053b8 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:106{53}]"MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.scale-125_contrast-white.png" of Mcrosoft-Windows-MicrosoftEdge, Version = 10.0.10240.16431, pA = amd64, nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35} in the store, hash mismatch

2000053b9 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:156{78}]"Package_536_for_KB3081444~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.0.3081444-875_neutral"

000053bc [SR] Could not reproject corrupted file [ml:142{71},l:140{70}]"\??\C:\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\Assets"\[l:106{53}]"MicrosoftEdgeSquare44x44.scale-125_contrast-white.png"; source file in store is also corrupted
```

Comment: No idea, but these are just icons, so is it that important?

Comment: I don't know whether it is important or not.

Comment: You get the good files from the .wim from an installation media but if icons files are corrupted right after installing, then you have a HDD that is starting to fail, system files located in WinSxS don't start becoming corrupt without a reason

Comment: @Ramhound Yonkers. Thank you for letting me know that my HDD is starting to fail.

Comment: @Ramhound I have asked a follow up question that you might be able to answer: http://superuser.com/questions/960484/how-do-we-check-the-hard-disc-health-on-a-surface-pro-3

Comment: @Ramhound I did a S.M.A.R.T. check using HDDScan. Everything looks good so it is probably something else.

Comment: Try running `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth` from an elevated command prompt or PowerShell window.  I got an error: `The source files could not be found.` but you may have better luck.  <shrug>  Another reason not use use Microsoft's browser(s), if you ask me.