# How do we check the hard disk health on a Surface Pro 3?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I am running Windows 10 on the Surface Pro 3. I would like to check the health of the hard disk, because some WinSxS files have become corrupted. How does one do this?

I have read [Tool to test HDD for health?](https://superuser.com/questions/520780/tool-to-test-hdd-for-health) It looks like it is manufacture specific. I have also read [How to check the health of a hard drive](https://superuser.com/questions/171195/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-hard-drive), and it seems to be Linux specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check the health of a hard drive](http://superuser.com/questions/171195/how-to-check-the-health-of-a-hard-drive)

Comment: Technically the SP3 has a SSD not a HDD.  Any program that checks the S.M.A.R.T data would be applicable.  Of course given the age of the SP3 it being a disk problem is greatly reduced.

Comment: Basically any app to check disk health that has been compiled for Windows RT.

Comment: @arielnmz but SP3 isn't an RT device.

Comment: You can open Device manager to check the manufacturer of the SSD and download his SSD testing tool.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Surface Diagnostic Toolkit, part of the Surface Tools for IT located on the Microsoft Website. It will prompt you run a battery of tests on your Surface, including a test on the health of the SSD.

Comment: Only for Surface 3 and newer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Windows Event Log for disk errors.

This is something you can do with stock Windows software, no add-ons. And the data has already been logged on your PC. ie this isn't a test you have to *start* running now; you can look for problems that occurred in the past.

Open Computer Management (run compmgmt.msc) and in the left pane, nav to System Tools | Event Viewer | Windows Logs , click System. In the right pane, click Filter Current Log. In the Event Sources selector, select "disk" and "Disk". OK. Your middle pane should now show all disk-related events.

If there aren't any "warning" or "error" level, you're good. :) You may be good even if there are a few, depending on what they are. If the text shows anything about "retries", though, that's bad.

Comment: Would the downvoter like to offer a reason?